# Запрет листинга корневого каталога при подключении SFTP (SSH File Transfer)

Tags: ssh, sftp

Пользователи подключаются к серверу через *SFTP*. При этом каждому из них доступен просмотр любого каталога на сервере, если права на каталог не `x00`.

Как можно ограничить пользователя? Дать возможность просматривать только свой домашний каталог?

Comment: Какую серверную программу для SFTP используете?

Comment: chroot устраивать пробовали?

Comment: [Аналогичный вопрос][1], только на англ. языке.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes

Comment: chroot ssh, lshell...

Comment: "любого каталога на сервере" - вы рутом, что ли, подключаетесь?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

в `openssh`, начиная с [версии 4.9](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-4.9), добавлена возможность делать `chroot` для пользователей.

для этого нужно в конец конфигурационного файла `sshd` (обычно `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) добавить такие строки (здесь подразумевается, что домашние каталоги располагаются в каталоге `/home`):

```
match group sftponly
chrootdirectory /home/%u
forcecommand internal-sftp
```

заодно убедитесь, что в этом файле присутствует строка, начинающаяся с `subsystem sftp`. если есть, но закомментирована — раскомментируйте. если же совсем отсутствует что-либо подобное, вставьте (выше строки, начинающейся с `match`) такую строку:

```
subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

после этого надо проверить корректность внесённых изменений:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -t
```

если проверка успешна, перезапустите `sshd`. обычно так:

```
$ sudo service ssh restart
```

затем нужно создать группу (вообще имя произвольное, можно использовать и другое, не забыв подправить его в вышеуказанном файле):

```
$ sudo groupadd sftponly
```

затем нужного пользователя(-ей) нужно добавить в эту группу. в debian и основанных на нём дистрибутивах (и ещё многих, не основанных) есть удобная программа `adduser`:

```
$ sudo adduser <имя пользователя> sftponly
```

в тех дистрибутивах, где нет такой программы, можно сделать примерно так:

```
$ sudo useradd -a -G sftponly <имя пользователя>
```

и, наконец, нужно сделать `root`-а владельцем домашнего каталога выбранного пользователя(-ей) и запретить другим возможность записи в этот каталог:

```
$ sudo chown root:root /home/<имя пользователя>
$ sudo chmod go-w /home/<имя пользователя>
```

---

**дополнение** по поводу домашнего каталога в директиве `chrootdirectory`.

если домашний каталог пользователя находится не в `/home`, имеет смысл в этой директиве использовать полный путь к домашнему каталогу с помощью `%h`:

```
chrootdirectory %h
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Заработало отлично! Как раз то, что мне нужно.