# vsftpd - настройка пользователей и каталогов

Tags: linux, ftp

Установил данный *фтп* сервер. Настроил *userlist* так, что те, кто есть в самой системе, могут использовать свою учетку и для *фтп*.

Иногда мне нужно дать права на *фтп* пользователю, которого нет в самой *убунте*, и этот пользователь не должен видеть все папки, для него, например я в корне определю /`myrootfolder` и все остальное не должно отображаться, он приконнектился и сразу находится в этой папке.

Что бы понять о чем я, пример: в винде использовал *file-zilla server*, вот там-то можно было все именно так настроить.

Для *vsftpd* я не нашел нужной информации.

Вообще, можно ли это сделать в данном *фтп* сервере?

Comment: можно. но, по-моему, *ftp* — это неправильное решение. гораздо универсальнее и безопасней, с моей точки зрения, использовать так называемый *sftp* (*ftp* поверх *ssh*). для этого варианта есть клиенты для всех популярных современных операционных систем.

Comment: *sftp* отлично подойдёт и для первой озвученной задачи («те кто есть в самой системе могут использовать свою учетку»), причём пароли пользователя не будут передаваться через интернет в открытом виде, как в случае *ftp*.

Comment: спасибо, попробую ssh

Comment: для справки: [по поводу *chroot* (ограничения «видимости»)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424663/178576)

Comment: ещё для справки: [ftp must die](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie)

Answer (score 2):

> можно ли это сделать в данном фтп сервере?

можно. но, по-моему, *ftp* — это неправильное решение. гораздо универсальнее и безопасней, с моей точки зрения, использовать так называемый *sftp* (*ftp* поверх *ssh*). для этого варианта есть клиенты для всех популярных современных операционных систем.

*sftp* отлично подойдёт и для первой озвученной задачи («те кто есть в самой системе могут использовать свою учетку»), причём пароли пользователя не будут передаваться через интернет в открытом виде, как в случае *ftp*.

для справки:

- [по поводу *chroot* (ограничения «видимости»)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424663/178576)
- [ftp must die](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie)