# Ограничить область видимости отдельных сайтов друг от друга

Tags: ubuntu, apache

Накатил на сервер apache2-mpm-itk для того, чтобы каждый сайт запускался под своим пользователем. Все работает, но я не хочу чтобы пользователи могли просматривать файловую структуру всего сервера.

Т.е., каждый сайт лежит в своей директории:

```
/var/www/example.ru/public_html/index.html
/var/www/example2.ru/public_html/index.html
```

Как сделать, чтобы пользователь сайта `example.ru` не мог подняться выше своей директории?

Comment: Для того чтобы юзер не мог посмотреть содержимое не своей директории  можно поставить права 750 или 700 для нее. Обычно хостеры этим ограничиваются. Готового решения для этой проблемы нет, нужно смотреть в сторону chroot.

Comment: но ведь тогда придется ставить права 750 на все директории выше, не думаю что это выход

Answer (score 1):

ограничить «видимость» пользователей можно, например, с помощью встроенной в *openssh* возможности делать *chroot* для пользователей.

смотрите ответ на этот вопрос: [Запрет листинга корневого каталога при подключении SFTP (SSH File Transfer)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424663/178576)