# Запрет на чтение всех файлов в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Хочу предоставить доступ к серверу третьим лицам, но хочу ограничить их область видимости, что бы они не могли ни чего видеть дальше свой домашней директории. Если я выставлю рекурсивно для гостей на все файлы запрещение на чтение. 
Будет ли ОС после этого работать нормально или это повлечёт за собой проблемы?

Comment: а как доступ будет предоставлен? если по ssh то там есть настройка которая запрещает пользователю перемещатся выще своей домащней(или любой другой) директории

Comment: а как закрыть перемещение выше домашней директории ?

Comment: то, что вы задумали, приведёт к неработоспособности вашей системы. возможно, вас устроит не предоставление shell-а, а предоставление файлового доступа: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424719/178576

Comment: Если вы предоставляете shell, то по крайней мере каталог `/tmp` должен доступен на запись. Посмотрите в сторону `chroot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Домашние директории могут иметь код доступа 750 и это никому не повредит.

Большинство программ будут работать нормально, если запретить читать директории (`find / -type d | xargs chmod o-r`) ничего не меняя с файлами.
Таким образом у пользователей сохранится возможность доступа к файлам если они точно знают имя (доступ к файлам обеспечивается x-битом директории).

Доступ к списку процессов можно ограничить при монтировании `/proc` опцией `hidepid`