# ограничить пользователя домашней папкой centos7

Tags: centos

Есть VPS сервер на centos7
Нужно создать пользователя, чтобы он мог заходить через ssh, но не мог выйти из своей домашней директории.
Когда я создаю пользователя, он может ходить по всему диску.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запрет листинга корневого каталога при подключении SFTP (SSH File Transfer)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424663/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-sftp-ssh-file-transfer)

Comment: Разрешите пользователю заходить по ssh под своим именем. Вы дали пользователям права root?