# Как отрыть доступ пользователю к конкретной папке по sftp?

Tags: linux, centos

есть папка

```
/var/www/site
```

она принадлежит пользователю site:site
создала нового пользователя из под рута,
настроила конфиг:
/

```
etc/ssh/sshd_config
#Subsystem      sftp        /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match User manager_user
ChrootDirectory /var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/upload/images_person
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Сохранила, ввела в консоли команды:

```
systemctl stop httpd
systemctl start httpd
```

Добавила manager_user в группу site.ru
При заходе по stfp - пишет, аутентификация не прошла...
ЛОГ:

```
Feb  5 17:15:47 site sshd[17844]: Accepted password for manager_user from ip port 30517 ssh2
Feb  5 17:15:47 site sshd[17844]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user manager_user by (uid=0)
Feb  5 17:15:47 site sshd[17844]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/var/www/site/" [postauth]
```

менять права на папку я не собираюсь, папка /var/www/site должна остаться за site.

Пользователь должен просматривать только папку, не заходя выше каталога.

> /var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/upload/images_person

Comment: С таким подходом не получится, openssh строго требует, чтобы владельцем всех папок от корня до `ChrootDirectory` был `root` и они были доступны на запись только ему... как вариант, можно получить какой-то компромиссный вариант symlink'ами или `bind`'ами; или воспользоваться pureftpd, например (хотя кому-то придётся переехать с 22-го порта)

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424663/178576)

Comment: [другой связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/678846/178576)

Comment: @Fat-Zer, скажите, пож-ста, как так делать? симлинками...

Answer (score 2):

> менять права на папку я не собираюсь, папка /var/www/site должна остаться за site.

С таким подходом не получится, openssh строго требует, чтобы владельцем всех папок от корня до `ChrootDirectory` был `root` и они были доступны на запись только ему.

Как вариант, можно получить какой-то компромиссный вариант symlink'ами, идея примерно следующая:

```
mkdir -pm 755 /home/manager_user_root/
chown root:site /home/manager_user_root/
mv /var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/upload/images_person /home/manager_user_root/
ln -s /home/manager_user_root/images_person /var/www/site/data/www/site.ru/upload/
```

В `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` соответственно

```
# ...
Match User manager_user
ChrootDirectory /home/manager_user_root/
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

У пользователя по sftp соответственно будет виден один каталог `images_person` и только в него возможна будет загрузка. Возможно потребуется небольшая правка конфигов web-сервера, если он запрещает следование по симлинкам, chroot'иться или ещё что-то. Аналогичного эффекта можно добиться с помощью `mount -o bind`.

Также можно использовать другие ftp серверы, если очень хочется соединятся именно по протоколу sftp, то в `pureftpd` есть соответствующий плагин. Но, если используются порты по умолчанию, кому-то придётся переехать с 22-го порта подальше за <s>МКАД</s> 1024-й порт.